# how to handle this exception :Invalidoperation exception

Tags: c#

```
Application.Run(form);
```

Actually I tried to call this from my project.  I got this exception.  How to solve it? I have already called another `Application.Run(frmBind);` in my project.

> Starting a second message loop on a single thread is not a valid
>   operation. Use Form.ShowDialog instead.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
    frmBind = new frmMain();

    Application.Run(frmBind);

    //args1 = string.Copy(args);
}
```

This is where I call the Application at first

Now again did it here:

```
try
{
   // Application.Run( form);
   form.ShowDialog();
}
```

Here the exception is thrown.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's telling you how to solve it:

```
 form.Show();
```

or if you want the new form to be modal:

```
 form.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: even after doing that the exception continues

Comment: You should *remove* the second Application.Run and use this instead.

Comment: did the same even after that exception continues so only posted this question

Comment: form.ShowDialog shouldn't give the previous exception, if at all. Are you sure you are testing correctly against the latest version?

Answer (score 4):

You can only call Application.Run once in a thread. Application.Run will (amongst other things) set up the main message loop for the thread, and there can be only one such loop. This is why you get the exception.

If you simply want to display a form, just use `form.Show()` or `form.ShowDialog()` instead. Note that calling ShowDialog for a form that is already visible will throw an InvalidOperationException as well (but with another message).

Comment: even after doing that the exception continues

Comment: You will need to show some code, I think. Otherwise it's really hard to help out.

Comment: Might it be that the form is already visible when you call ShowDialog?